# create random array without duplicate elements together

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array same as following:

```
$myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
```

I need to contact this items with a string in a loop and I try same as following:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $myArray[array_rand($myArray)] . '-' . $product['name']   
}
```

And this could be the output of that

> c - red book
>   c - black phone
>   a - green book
>   e - pink laptop
>   a - blue shirt

As you can see, the two first rows are prefixed with the same, which is not acceptable here. Repetitions are fine (the same prefix can occur multiple times), but not in two rows next to each other.

Comment: Can you elaborate how is `$product` relevant here?

Comment: @vivek_23 I get products from db

Comment: That's fine, but how does that affect duplicacy from `$myArray` ? I think you should focus only on `$myArray` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the previous value in a variable, then generate a new random value until its different than the previous one - so a little recursive check. We also add a check for `count($myArray) > 1`, in case there's only 1 value in the array (that would cause an infinite loop).

We use a `while` loop because there's a chance, albeit very minor, that if the value is equal to the previous, that also the following value is equal to the previous one. In reality, the while loop is usually never iterated more than once for the majority of items (which is how I justify using a loop in a loop).

```
$previous = null;
foreach($products as $product) {
    do {
        $prefix = $myArray[array_rand($myArray)];
    } while ($prefix === $previous && count($myArray) > 1);
    $previous = $prefix;
    echo $prefix . '-' . $product['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the previously used key and iterate over your rand until you get a new key:

```
$previous_key = '';
foreach ($products as $product) {

    do {
        $key = array_rand($myArray);
    } while ($previous_key === $key);

    echo $myArray[$key] . '-' . $product['name'];

    $previous_key = $key;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I think as an improvement, you can unset the index, do an array_rand for the next one and then set this unset one back again.

Comment: You should be using `$myArray[$key]` instead of `$myArray[array_rand($myArray)]` in your echo-line.

Comment: Right you are @Qirel - fixed!